# ASP and Django on same hosting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, django, webserver, hosting

Can I have both a page using ASP.NET MVC 4 and another using Django under the same hosting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , you can config your web server to serve django project at the same host with ASP.Net or with some php application

otherwise you can install apache with iis and config apache to load django project and iis to load ASP.Net application
you can manage it by manage their ports
for example port 80 for IIS and port 8080 for apache
if you want to do it you should install wsgi_mod in apache 
you can see here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/modwsgi/

---

Regards
Mohammad

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just configure your web server to serve Django separately from ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve ASP.NET you need a Windows-based server. Serving Django from Windows is not a big problem, but you will probably not be able to do it from a shared hosting account. Shared windows hosting is usually locked down / limited so much that hosting Django is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Daniel Eriksson ... It will be difficult to control hosting environment for Django on shared server. Moreover, I do not see Django listed on Microsoft's Web Platform Installer (http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/categories.aspx) application list. That means, it might be difficult to setup & take true benefits of  dJango application on Windows platform.

If you still decide to host asp.net + django on a windows platform, go for a VPS hosting.